# When do the log files in IBM MobileFirst Analytics get created?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-analytics

I can download logs file via analytics console > Devices > Device Search > Device Information > Download Logs

I'd like to know when do the log files get created and updated?

Answer (score 0):

The logs get created once a device has registered in the server and mention of this arrived to the analytics database, which you can then view in the Analytics console. Once you click the download button the file gets generated with the latest available data and is downloaded.

Explain your question further so a fuller answer could be provided.

Comment: When do the log files get updated, with the new log data?? 
I have run my application, and the last timestamp": "08-06-15 10:04:48:129.. And i run my application once again, no newer log data in the logs file

Comment: I'm with Idan.  Please write a better question.  What version of the product are you on?  What does your code do?  What is the logger configuration?  How often do you call the logger to send?  Do you call it at all?  What expectations do you have?  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Logs from an application on a device (or any other MobileFoundation supported environment) are only sent to the server, and therefore to the Analytics data store, when the application logs are explicitly sent via API call:

```
WL.Logger.send();  // JavaScript
[OCLogger send];  // objective-c (iOS)
Logger.send();  // Java (Android)
```

These functions are called automatically after your application calls WLClient.connect or WLClient.invokeProcedure.  If your app calls neither of these, you must explicitly call send().  It's a bit confusing, I know, but that's the current implementation.

Comment: hello mikerott, yes i have called invokeProcedure, it means that function is called automatically, but the newer logs data not updated in my logs file

Answer (score 0):

The newer data updated in the logs file until the queue size are fullfiled.

We must setting the wl.analytics.queue.size in the server.xml
Sets the number of individual analytics data that each queue can hold. The total number of analytics data that the server can hold at one time before it begins to drop data is (wl.analytics.queues * wl.analytics.queue.size)